# Opencart Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: configuration-files, opencart, fatal-error

Trying to move from local host to new server. Fresh install worked fine, no problems. When I uploaded my files mydomain.com/admin comes up with a white screen and mydomain.com produces this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home4/pawpostc/public_html/index.php on line 103.

So I took a look at index.php line 103:

```
if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
        echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on     line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
    }
```

Seems like there is a problem with my config files. So I went and had a look at them. I have gone over them a few times but can not find the mistake, probably missing something, so here are the config files.

config.php (in my root www. folder):

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/catalog/language/');   
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'my user name');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'my database');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
?>
```

admin/config.php:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/admin/'); 
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.pawpost.com.au/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home4/pawpostc/public_html/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'my user name');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'my database');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
?>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: check permissions(owner:groop) for file system/library/config.php

Answer (score 3):

I was using opencart and installed vqmod.
All of a sudden I have one of the same errors.

This solved my problem:
in system/library/session.php
replace start session with:

```
session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../tmp'));
```

Comment: this is a great solution. Thank you, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that one or more of your library files are corrupt from uploading. Re upload your `system/library/` folder from your local one. Your config files seem fine and the error doesn't reference a config issue. What is line 103 in your `index.php` file?

Comment: the first code box in the post is line 103. I'll give the library upload a shot.

Comment: Check pawpost.com.au/index1.php if you can. I uploaded the system/library folder, no change. I will go through each of the files.

Comment: Check `/system/library/config.php` and also the `index.php` file itself to make sure they match exactly. Your error means that `$config` isn't the object it's meant to be (a `Config` class) which is generally due to the library file being corrupt

Comment: I just did a fresh reinstall and am re-entering my database, wasn't that big anyway.

Answer (score 0):

please cross check you have set all permissions 
  i had came across this error and was solved,
  that was due to a file permission problem

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem after migrating my site to a new VPS environment. I figured it HAD to be something to do with the changed document-root path or permissions of my shop and pulled out a lot of hair trying to get to the core of the problem.

I finally realised that I had incorrect permissions on my PHP session-data store! In my case, the folder at /var/lib/php/session/ was owned by apache (naturally) but I had changed apache to run as a different user so it could no longer write to the session-store.

The error messages in this case are cryptic (to say the least!) and didn't give a clue that the problem might just be lack of write permission!

Oh well, we should know by now that 90% of unix issues are down to perms!

Answer (score 0):

I upload a file at my server (directory: vqmod/....php ).

Just change vqmod file permission. I set 777 and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you received, it looks like the `$config` variable is not getting set.
The `$config` variable is set on line 35 using the `Config` class which is located in `system/library/config.php`

I think if you figure out why the class isn't getting instantiated, you'll be able to fix the issue.
This could be a couple things:

- The `system/library/config.php` file may not have been uploaded to the new server
- As mentioned in previous answers, there could be a permissions issue.  Check the permissions of `system/library/config.php` and make sure the correct user has ownership.
- Or it could be a completely unrelated issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to permissions set on the cache folder. Setting that to 755 and the files to 555 with set you home and dry.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I changed vqmod permission to 777. I am not sure this solved the problem, but I checked my website without adding www. before the domain and it worked. The warning was removed if I check http://daytodaystore.com. If I check http://www.daytodaystore.com, the warning is there.

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem when i migrated my server from 2G to 4GH on Godaddy.
Came across this forum and found that the issue is with session.php
Then, i guessed 'tmp' folder was missing. So, i created one just one step above html folder. and gave it a 777 access. Problem was fixed and my website looks great after that.