# Opencart 500 server error

Tags: opencart, internal-server-error

I am getting such an error at image below while **OpenCart** complete the pay option. How could this be solved?
hi when I want to click Continue button to continue the order after i finish my payment method then it goes to Checkout Confirmation" The continue button to checkout confirmation does not function it freeze like no action to take. but i look in code. i go to some javascript code. to continue it i try to trace which action it will take i think this javascript

They have the same problem with me. They have solved the problem here, but I do not know how they do it Opencart Fatal error: [Opencart Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737880/opencart-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-get-on-a-non-object/41827508?noredirect=1#comment70841796_41827508)
[image: js error image]

Comment: It does not seems to be a `JavaScript` error. You should check your server (`apache`/`nginx`) logs to get a more specific idea of what caused this error in that route controller.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest. I am seeing such an error when I look at the logs from PLesk: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function check () on a non-object in C: \ Inetpub \ vhosts \ trendbirter \ httpdocs \ catalog \ model \ checkout \ order. Php on line 267

Comment: 267. Line Code: http://i.hizliresim.com/2nz7v0.png

Comment: which version of opencart are you using?

Comment: I using 2.3.2 so latest version.